# Android 7 (Sony Z4) xmlHTTPRequest takes sometimes very long

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, android-7.0-nougat

In my application I request a resource via JavaScript.

In Test 1 I use the native XMLHttpRequest. 
In Test 2 I use use Jquery 1.9.1

Test 1

```
function getResource(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/test/empty.html", false);
    xhr.send("");
    var result = xhr.responseText;
}
```

Test 2

```
function getResource(){
    var config = {
        url: http://localhost:8080/test/empty.html,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //handle error
        },
        async: false
    };

    jQuery.ajax(config);
}
```

For both test cases the same results are investigated.

**Invatigation:**

- The request normally takes ~130ms. But very often it takes much
  more time from 1s to 30s
- This only appears on an android 7.0(Nougat) device (sony Z4)
- What we found out, that the server (Tomcat 7) got the response and send the request back to the client. 
  The client is waiting for it, but dont get the response(In Chrome network Tab empty.html is pending). Somehow the server got an new response from the client and send back the request again. This repeats until the client recognize the response.

PS:
I got an hint, that this is maybe an issue with JQuery 1.9 and an upgrade to 2.X will fix this. 
But I cannot upgrade my application so easily to an newer version of JQuery.

What can i do that this kind of device get the response in ms?

Comment: How can you be sure it's not a network issue?

Comment: if it's localhost, it can't be a network issue

Comment: `async:false` ?

Comment: On my application it runs with the correct ip <serverip>:<port>/<contextspath>. I want to have an synchronisly request for this kind of source.